# Why does Mac OS X ignore my Windows NTFS and Share permissions?

Tags: windows, mac-osx, permissions

Mac OS X Snow Leopard
Windows Server 2003

**Windows Folder "Videos"**
Share Permissions on Videos
- Everyone
NTFS Permissions on Videos
- System (Full Control)
- Domain Users (Modify)
- Domain Admins (Full Control)

Mac user Michael is a part of the Domain Users group.  He connects to Videos using cifs://server/Videos and authenticates with his username Michael.  Michael copies over a file "dance dance baby.avi".

User Jon opens the Videos folder but cannot see the dance dance baby.avi file.

Checking the dance dance baby.avi file permissions here is what I see:

Everyone - Read, Write
Domain Admins - Full Control
Michael - Read, Write
Owner of File - Michael

So here's my question, how come when Michael copies a file over from a Mac, the permissions on the file get changed even though Michael has no rights to change permissions?

If the same file is copied over from a Windows machine, it just inherits the proper permissions from the parent Video folder.

Am I missing something?  Are my permissions wrong?  Thanks.

Michael

Comment: Whenever a file is created, the process creating it can set whatever permissions it likes.  Also, the owner of a file - the account that created it - can always change the permissions.  You can mitigate the second issue by setting "modify" instead of "full" permission on the share.

Comment: Actually, if you remove the CREATOR OWNER permissions they won't be able to take ownership of the file.  Yes I have the perms set as modify instead of full.  The problem has been solved, it's because I was using cifs not smb.

Comment: just to confirm, the share permissions are set as "Everyone: Modify"?  The question doesn't say.

Comment: CREATOR OWNER permissions don't have anything to do with being able to take ownership.  When a file is created, the person who created it is the owner and (unless blocked by share permissions) will be able to change the permissions on it.

Comment: However, if I understand your problem rightly, none of this matters; you don't actually want to stop users from deliberately changing permissions, you just want the default permissions set the way you want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using smb:// instead of cifs:// to connect fixed the issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Although its main purpose is file sharing, additional Microsoft SMB Protocol functionality includes the following:
- File, directory, and share access authentication

Comment: This issue is occurring (again?) even when using SMB://.. Here is a similar thread.  The issue is marked as resolved, but it definitely is NOT.   http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28430958/Mac-OS-X-Mavericks-causing-problems-with-Windows-2012-R2-server-shares.html  I had to remove Write permissions from the .TemporaryItems folder.